# Can't animate location of characters in text individually

Tags: animation, text-object

Here's the blend file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=44670. If you keyframe the location of the letter "I" at a different location and then move the greenbar the rest of the letters will follow its origin. I've been looking for answers on the internet and can't find a solution.

Comment: P.S. here at stack exchange we pefer if you use Blend-Exchange, http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ,  for the files will never will never expire. Just for future reference ;)

Answer (score 1):

All the letters have strips in the [NLA Editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/en/editors/nla/usage.html) which share the same action:

[image: screenshot all letters share the same action]

But this action contains nothing so it looks like the letters aren't animated. For this same reason you can use *Remove Emtpy Animation Data* option to remove all the empty strips:

[image: screenshot removing empty animation data]